# Preserve quotes and also add data with quotes in Ruamel

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am using Ruamel to preserve quote styles in human-edited YAML files.

I have example input data as:

```
---
a: '1'
b: "2"
c: 3
```

I read in data using:

```
def read_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as _f:
        return ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(_f.read(), preserve_quotes=True)
```

I then edit that data:

```
data = read_file('in.yaml')
data['foo'] = 'bar'
```

I write back to disk using:

```
def write_file(f, data):
    with open(f, 'w') as _f:
        _f.write(ruamel.yaml.dump(data, Dumper=ruamel.yaml.RoundTripDumper, width=1024))

write_file('out.yaml', data)
```

And the output file is:

```
a: '1'
b: "2"
c: 3
foo: bar
```

Is there a way I can enforce hard quoting of the string 'bar' without also enforcing that quoting style throughout the rest of the file?

(Also, can I stop it from deleting the three dashes `---` ?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to preserve quotes (and literal block style) for string scalars, ruamel.yaml¹—in round-trip-mode—represents these scalars as  `SingleQuotedScalarString`, `DoubleQuotedScalarString` and `PreservedScalarString`. The class definitions for these very thin wrappers can be found in `scalarstring.py`. 
When serializing such instances are written "as they were read", although sometimes the representer falls back to double quotes when things get difficult, as that can represent any string.

To get this behaviour when adding new key-value pairs (or when updating an existing pair), you just have to create these instances yourself:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import SingleQuotedScalarString, DoubleQuotedScalarString

yaml_str = """\
---
a: '1'
b: "2"
c: 3
"""

yaml = YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.explicit_start = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['foo'] = SingleQuotedScalarString('bar')
data.yaml_add_eol_comment('# <- single quotes added', 'foo', column=20)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives:

```
---
a: '1'
b: "2"
c: 3
foo: 'bar'          # <- single quotes added
```

the `yaml.explicit_start = True` recreates the (superfluous) document start marker. Whether such a marker was in the original file or not is not "known" by the top-level dictionary object, so you have to re-add it by hand.

Please note that without `preserve_quotes`, there would be (single) quotes around the values `1` and `2` anyway to make sure they are seen as string scalars and not as integers.

---

¹ <sub>Of which I am the author.</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much, that is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Since Ruamel 0.15, set the preserve_quotes flag like this:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
from pathlib import Path

yaml = YAML(typ='rt') # Round trip loading and dumping
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(Path("in.yaml"))
yaml.dump(data, Path("out.yaml"))
```